# Initialise a Date of Birth with a DateTime or three integers?

Tags: c#

I recently asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582699/equality-for-a-dateofbirth-value-object.  I am going to avoid a `DateOfBirth` value object.  Instead I am planning to use a type alias.  I have a few options with regards to my constructor:

**Option 1**

```
using DateOfBirth=System.DateTime;
DateOfBirth DateOfBirth;    

public Person (DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
     if (dateOfBirth.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds > 0)
         throw new ArgumentException("Date of birth cannot contain a time.")
     DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

**Option 2**

```
DateOfBirth DateOfBirth;   
public Person(int day, int month, int year)
{
   //Validation to make sure day, month and year are valid.
   DateOfBirth = new DateOfBirth(year,month,day);
}
```

I am trying to decides, which option to choose.  The validation for option two could be quite complex because some months have different number of days.  Therefore I am hoping that option one is suitable for this.

Also, should I be using type aliases in my Unit Tests or just refer to them as the primitive type i.e. date time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your option one is a bad idea. If you are using a `DateTime`, call it a `DateTime`.

```
public Person (DateTime dateOfBirth)
```

is very clear, whereas your variant with a `using` is cryptic.

If you want to be able to have business rules specific to a date of birth (which is reasonable, given that many `DateTime` values won't necessarily be valid birth dates), your best option could be to inherit from `DateTime`. Unfortunately, you won't be able to do it, since [`DateTime` is a `struct`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs).

Therefore, create your own class, and put a `DateTime` field inside it. Implementing comparisons in this case is pretty straightforward, since you can delegate all the work to the underlying `DateTime`. You still need to handle [`==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx).

Inside this class, you'll be able to do input validation (within the constructor), to extract the data you need (i.e. keep the date and drop the time), and well as ensure that the callers can only get the information they need, and never be able to access the underlying `DateTime` field.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to handle all comparisons eg <, >, <=, >= etc.

Comment: That depends entirely on your needs. Are you going to compare dates of birth quite often in the source? (Validations aside)

Comment: @Laiv, yes I am.  For example, the domain logic has to assess what age category the Person is in e.g. under 18, 18-35, 35-50 etc.

Comment: Those are age ranges, not dates of birth :-). Basically, you only need to perform the next operation `todayDate - dateOfBirth`. But not comparisons between dates. In other words, the next statement is semantically wrong `dateOfbirth is between 35 and 50`.

Comment: @Laiv, I don't understand what you mean.  Could you clarify? Perhaps in an answer? I do this: If DateOfBirth < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18).  This will tell me if the person is under 18

Comment: @Laiv, your expression returns a TimeSpan.  However, the TimeSpan structure does not have a years property.  How do I get the years? I don't believe I can divide TimeSpan.Days by 365 because there are leap years.

Comment: @Arseni Mourzenko, could you answer my first comment before I accept? Is it not a bad idea to delegate  all the work to the underlying datetime as it breaks encapsulation?

Comment: @w0051977: Checking that a time difference is more than 18 years doesn't tell you the person is 18 years old. Rules for "date of birth" are different. Date of birth is independent of the time zone. Date of birth is the day when you were born, based on the time zone of your location at the time. You are eighteen when its the same day again, in your _current_ location.

Comment: @gnasher729, If all my users use the western idea of age (rather than East Asian Reckoning) then I assume that I do not have an issue?

Comment: @w0051977 In support of Arseni's "call it a DateTime" argument: what would you do if you needed to pass both a `dateOfBirth` and `dateOfDeath`? Your assumption of renaming the type relies solely on the fact that you happen to only need _one_ datetime parameter. A type should not reflect the _meaning_ of the parameter (that's what the parameter name is supposed to be used for). You wouldn't rename `int` to `age` just because this person has an Age property of type int, no?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are another option.  As you feel the concept of date without time component has merit for your domain, then what is important here is that ***the validation happens as soon as you have the date***, rather than waiting for validation inside the `Person` constructor.  To do this you would use a simple wrapper class as follows:

```
class DateOnly {
    public readonly DateTime Value;
    public DateOnly ( DateTime value ) {
       if ( value.Date != value )
           throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "time component not allowed" );
       Value = value;
    }
    public DateOnly ( int year, int month, int day ) {
        Value = new DateTime ( year, month, day );
    }
}


class Person {
     Person ( DateOnly birthDate ) { }
}
```

Comment: and as @Arseni says, don't forget == and Equals...

Comment: Wouldn't I have to handle all nine equality operators? Eg <, >, <=, >= etc,

Comment: No, unless you want to do relations on `DateOnly`.  Since you can always access the underlying `DateTime Value`, you can do your other comparisons on that directly. The reason to handle the == and Equals is so your class `DateOnly` works nicely with hash tables and such.

Comment: Please see my question here and specifically the comments under the last answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186590/equality-for-a-dateofbirth-value-object/186647?noredirect=1#comment356155_186647

Comment: The answerer seems to think that you should not access the encapsulated value directly.  What do you think.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would tend to agree, however, I also think that concern applies more as we get to higher levels of abstraction towards of your domain entities.  Here we're just dealing with a fairly simple value abstraction, theres' just not much encapsulation to loose by accessing the underlying `DateTime`.  `DateTime` has a lot of features, which you could spend a lot of time replicating, and I just don't see the value offered by the encapsulation argument making that replication worthwhile. YMMV.

Comment: Also, you might consider a struct over a class for this.  (And don't forget `GetHashCode()` as well.)

Comment: I was thinking about using an Object because of what is described here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/12/04/net-value-type-ddd-value-object/.  The blogger suggests using a class rather than object.  Do you agree?

Comment: I see the date of birth as being an attribute (a column) in the person table.  Thus, it does not need to persist independently.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that it DateOfBirth should be a Struct?

Comment: DateOfBirth is, I think, an ideal example of the kind of thing that *should* be a struct.  It represents a *value*, and can be copied around into difference places, but there's never any reason why if you change it one place the change should be reflected in another, which is the primary difference between structs and classes.  I also see no reason you'd ever want to subclass it, which is the second difference.

Comment: @Eric Eidt, How would I tell users of the class not to use <, >, <=, >= etc if I wanted them to use DateOfBirth.Value?

Comment: If you omit the definitions of the ordered relations, and provide the .Value operation, then that's what they'll use when they want to compare the date in two `DateOnly` types.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm advocating a simple `DateOnly` data type, which should probably be a struct (not a `DateOfBirth` data type).

Comment: @Erik Eidt, I want to compare dates e.g. see if a person is 18 years old.  Please see gnasher729 comment above under Arseness answer.  If all my users use the western idea of age (rather than East Asian Reckoning) then I assume that I do not have an issue?

Comment: How would you validate the three integers passed to the constructor? I was thinking about using DateTime.TryParse, however that requires the DateTime to be a DateTime and not three integers.